# Trouble inserting 4-Byte UTF-8 characters / emoji into MySQL Database when insert trigger is active

Tags: mysql, utf-8, triggers, utf8mb4

I'm having trouble with a database trigger that logs all queries performed on a table, when that query contains a 4-Byte UTF-8 character.

My [mysql.cnf](https://pastebin.com/3cix3GzZ)

mysql version is 5.7.19 on Ubuntu 16.04

Example script:

```
show variables where Variable_name like 'character\_set\_%' or Variable_name like 'collation%';

drop database if exists my_test_db;
create database my_test_db;
use my_test_db;

create table my_test_table(id int not null primary key auto_increment, jdoc json not null);
create table my_test_table_log(id int not null primary key auto_increment, query varchar(1024) NOT NULL);

SELECT "insert works when trigger is not active" as "";
insert into my_test_table(jdoc) VALUES(JSON_OBJECT("Dubai was", ""));

DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER log_my_test_table_queries_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON `my_test_table`
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE original_query VARCHAR(1024);
    SET original_query = (SELECT info
                          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST
                          WHERE id = CONNECTION_ID());
    INSERT INTO `my_test_table_log` (`query`) VALUES (original_query);
  END;
|
DELIMITER ;

SELECT "insert doesn't work when trigger is active" as "";
insert into my_test_table(jdoc) VALUES(JSON_OBJECT("Dubai was", ""));
```

My output:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

+-----------------------------------------+
|                                         |
+-----------------------------------------+
| insert works when trigger is not active |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

+--------------------------------------------+
|                                            |
+--------------------------------------------+
| insert doesn't work when trigger is active |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5")...' for column 'INFO' at row 1
```

The Databases seem to be created with the correct character set

```
SHOW CREATE TRIGGER log_my_test_table_queries_insert;
SHOW CREATE TABLE my_test_table;
SHOW CREATE TABLE my_test_table_log;
```

[outputs](https://pastebin.com/yRP6RDSq)

detailsdetailsdetails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `information_schema.processlist` is using UTF8mb3 character set.  (UTF is an alias to UTFmb3).  This simple query illustrate this:

```
mysql> select info, "" from information_schema.processlist;
+------------------------------------------------------+------+
| info                                                 | ?    |
+------------------------------------------------------+------+
| select info, "?" from information_schema.processlist |      |
+------------------------------------------------------+------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5" ...' for column 'INFO' at row 1
```

The above warning probably result in an error when the trigger tries to insert the content of the `info` column into another table.

I think the problem is that the query string is stored as is in the `processlist` table without converting it to the expected character set. I have filed a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87579) about this.

Comment: Are there any news?

Answer (score 0):

Do these

```
SHOW CREATE TRIGGER log_my_test_table_queries_insert;
SHOW CREATE TABLE my_test_table;
SHOW CREATE TABLE my_test_table_log;
```

I suspect you will find that they were created with the wrong charset in effect.

Changing this one line may suffice:

```
create database my_test_db CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

(I can't reproduce the problem with your test case.  What version of MySQL or MariaDB are you using?)

Comment: I added some additional information to the original post. Sadly explicitely specifying the character set on the database creation didn't fix the problem. utf8mb4 is specified globally in the mysql.cnf file

Comment: What do you mean by reproducing? Does the script execute without issue on your machine?