# Why can't I store 4 byte emojis in this mysql field?

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a database in which I require that only two fields in one table allow for 4 byte emojis to be stored. I did this (obviously with the correct table and column names):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I know it worked, because when I do `show create table chatbots_proposalarea;` it shows me this:

```
CREATE TABLE `chatbots_proposalarea` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `proposal` varchar(1500) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `candidate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `chatbots_proposalare_candidate_id_6465160e_fk_chatbots_` (`candidate_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `chatbots_proposalare_candidate_id_6465160e_fk_chatbots_` FOREIGN KEY (`candidate_id`) REFERENCES `chatbots_candidate` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

The fields "name" and "proposal" do seem to have the uft8mb4_bin collation, and it showed no error when running the commands. However, when I try and save a value there such as "Seguridad ", it gives me the error

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8D\x9E' for column 'name' at row 1
```

Any help in discovering what am I missing would be very appreciated.

**NOTES**

This is on a Django project, and mounted on an Ubuntu server, and the SQL version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28, for Linux (x86_64)`
I don't see why that would make a difference, but the same happens when I update directly to the database by doing

```
UPDATE chatbots_proposalarea SET name='Seguridad ' where id=1;
```

A solution was recommended, but that one depended on the usage of triggers, and that was the cause of the issue, which isn't my case.

**UPDATE**

If it shows any important information, when I run `show variables where Variable_name like 'character\_set\_%' or Variable_name like 'collation%';`
I get the following:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

I changed these values to the same that a coworker has in one of his projects, in which he also requires 4 byte emojis to be stored.

Comment: I tested this and it works for me. Using MySQL 5.7.27.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble inserting 4-Byte UTF-8 characters / emoji into MySQL Database when insert trigger is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549840/trouble-inserting-4-byte-utf-8-characters-emoji-into-mysql-database-when-inser)

Comment: I see a lot of "utf8" in those system variables. It should all be "utf8mb4".

Comment: Yeah, mine are all 'utf8mb4' except for `character_set_system` which cannot be changed.

Comment: I changed the variables and it remains the same, I updated the question

Comment: You need to re-create the database after you changed the variables.You can create a new one to test.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the table's fault; it is the connection.  Something like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'charset': 'utf8mb4',
                    'use_unicode': True, },
    },
}
```

Comment: Although the same happens when I go directly and make an UPDATE statement directly on the mysql console, and that wouldn't be the case, or would it? Not just when I update through Django.

Comment: Each connection controls its own charset (etc) options.  What I showed is for Django.  The commandline "mysql" tool can use `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` before running queries.